# Flutter different alignment in Column

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a column with three rows:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    print('card of course clicked');
  },
  child: Card(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: 
    BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
    child: Container(
      height: 144,
      child: Row(children: [
        Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
                child: Image.network(_model._schoolThumb))),
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 16),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(_model._schoolName,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      fontSize: 18)),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 12),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.location_on, color: Colors.grey[700]),
                Container(width: 8),
                Text(_model._guides,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 14,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 12),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.attach_money, color: Colors.grey[700]),
                Container(width: 8),
                Text(_model._priceFrom,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 14,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400))
              ],
            )
           ],
         )
        ]),
        ),
       ),
     );
   }
```

As a result, I have three rows aligned to start.

How can I align the first `Text()` in the center? Giving properties to the text and wrapping in `Expanded`, `Container`, `Stack` didn't help, or I did it in the wrong way. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Whole `build()` method attached

Comment: use Align() widget.

Comment: Flutter Layout cheat sheet https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-layout-cheat-sheet-5363348d037e

Comment: @RubensMelo wrapping text with `Align` didn't help

Comment: @TinusJackson thanks, but I didn't find the solution in the article

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**
You haven't given a width to the column so it does not know the remaining width that it can take. So wrap your column in a flexible which will give it the width remaining to expand.

```
  Flexible(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(height: 16),
                  Row(
```

Comment: Works fine in mine... Then your Column is affected by its parent

Comment: I have `build()` method.

Comment: I mean copy my build method and try

Comment: But I have a different parent. How can use it my layout even if it works?

Answer (score 18):

**Problem:**

By default, the `width` of the `Column` is set to the `width` of the widest `child` widget of `Column`.

**Solution:**

You need to wrap your `Column` with either `Expanded` or `Flexible`.

Like below.

```
Expanded(
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      ...
    ],
  ),
)
```

or

```
Flexible(
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      ...
    ],
  ),
)
```

And then need to use the `Align` or `Center` widget to set the alignment to your child widget in your case the `Text` widget.

Like below:

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  child: Text(
    "Test",
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.black,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
      fontSize: 18,
    ),
  ),
),
```

or

```
Center(
  child: Text(
    "Test",
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.black,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
      fontSize: 18,
    ),
  ),
),
```